# How to get the correct file type of uploaded file which is with wrong extension?

Tags: java, .net

eg.  We can change a.txt file name as a.doc. But still the file type is 'Text Document', it is not converted into 'Doc' file. So, I want coding to recognize the type of such file.. In this case, 'a.doc' file should return the type of file as 'Text Document'. Not as 'Doc'.

Answer (score 1):

There is but one way as far as I know: you'd have to recognize the type of file by its content.

A generic way to deal with that is to not look at the whole file but only the first X bytes (which will generally be the file header) and try to find a recognizable marker in there. Many file types start with an identifying byte sequence for example.